# Ruby Time Calculations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I am trying to determine the duration of elapsed time minus any interruptions. The method below seems inefficient and silly is there a better method?

The user specifies an end_time and a start_time are and records any interruptions as an integer representing minutes.

```
def duration
  ((end_time - start_time).seconds - interrupt.minutes) / 60
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to subtract minutes from seconds? Shouldn't it be `interrupt.minutes * 60`?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what's inefficient or silly about it! The code seems to be fairly expressive, although the `.seconds` thing may be unnecessary. How much more efficient and sensible do you think it might be?

Comment: Oh, @Swanand - I just checked: everything's in seconds, so 4.minutes returns 240 seconds. Perhaps the function should return seconds, and leave display in minutes to formatting?

Comment: The OP and I feel it isn't intuitive code. It's more open to misinterpretation than we would like (I suspect Swanand's reaction is typical).  It also relies on time objects being internally represented as seconds and usable as POD numerics in arithmetic expressions, two facts that are implied but not explicitly stated in the ruby documentation. It felt wrong to write code that depends on that behavior.  But hey, it's good enough and it works.  We were just hoping to write more readable code next time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the [Benchmarks Module?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html)

Seems to do exactly what you want and it's part of the Ruby core libraries.

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report block_to_time
end
```

It's output is very similar to the unix time command. Detailing time spent in kernel space, time spent in user space and total CPU time, and the real elapsed time.

Comment: I should have clarified (and now have) this these values are from user inputs. Though the Benchmarks Module though seems really useful otherwise.